# How to use a blittable type representing a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the ReadUsingPointer Method described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25896/Reading-Unmanaged-Data-Into-Structures) to have a light spead binary reader for huge binary files. 
However, the struct I am trying to pass to it contains strings. I was wondering how I could circumvent this and avoid the "cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type" message

I tried the following with no success so far (maybe having accessors to these fields is the problem?):

```
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
 string s;
```

I have to specify that these string fields are used after reading and are not assigned while reading the bytes, so I do not need them while reading (I could use an intermediary struct without these fields but for legacy issues I can't do this).

Comment: `UnmanagedMemoryStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So does your unmanaged structure contain arrays of characters? There really isn't any practical way (that I know of) to model that on the managed side in a way that will be compatible with bulk copying since both strings and arrays are reference types on the managed side - if you declare a string in a .NET struct then the actual characters don't really reside there - only a string pointer does. Same with arrays.

Comment: This is no longer true with [fixed size buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers)